# How to configure gmail SMTP on IIS 8 and php localhost

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, iis-8

I am running php site on IIS server, I want to send emails locally using gmail smtp.

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

auth_username = name@89@gmail.com
auth_password =password 
sendmail_from = from @gmail.com
```

I set this setting in php.ini.

It give this error when I tries to run script.

> "The following SMTP error was encountered: 10061 No connection could
>   be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\nUnable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.
> User-Agent:
>   CodeIgniter\r\nDate"

Comment: 1-Show the code that uses those variables to send the mails. 2-Is the server able to connect to the google SMTP server? Try telnetting smtp.gmail.com on port 587 from the server and see if it works, maybe a fw in blocking the server.

Comment: $config = Array( 'protocol' => 'smtp','smtp_host' => "smtp.gmail.com",
                            'smtp_port' => 587,
                            'smtp_user' => "name@gmail.com",
                            'smtp_pass' => "password",
                         );
                        $this->load->library('email', $config); if($this->email->send())
                        {
                             "success";
                        }else{
                           
                          $this->email->print_debugger();
                        }